# JMeter Non GUI mode Test Execution number of samples mismatching

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmx, jmeter-4.0

I'm executing multiple scripts for 1 hr in Non GUI Mode. I'm having couple of questions here.

Test Scripts:-
Script1
Script2
Script3

- Number of Samples are differing with respect to the scenarios. I need equal distribution for all 3 scenarios. How to achieve this?
- I'm saving all 3 scripts in one .jmx file( keeping 3 thread groups and assigning 20 Users per script). Is it correct approach.
- I have added assertions for each request to check the response is valid or not.In loadrunner we will keep outside of Transactions but in Jmeter I'm not sure.  Do we need to keep them during execution window.

I'm really looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to achieve equal number of samples in all 3 scripts in Jmeter as response times for all 3 requests will be different. And there is no such thing as pacing in Jmeter as was there in Loadrunner. Only think time u can add as constant timer according to ur perception.
One reason  of discrepancy could be the Ramp up time. You should give same ramp up period in all 3 thread groups. if ramp up time is different discrepancy in number of samples is expected.
I would be able to help if you could provide some more info like:
1. How much is the RT for each req
2. How much think time u r giving for each.
3. How much ramp up time u giving for each thread group.
4. How much startup delay u r giving.